# "I let him do it" and "I allow him to do it", why exactly does one require 'to'?

Tags: verbs, infinitives, particles

> I let him do it.

and

> I allow him to do it.

Why does the latter require *to*?

What are the "rules" of using *to* with an infinitive? When is it necessary?

Answer (score 4):

In both OP's examples the verb ***do*** is an "infinitive". The *basic* rule  is the infinitive is "marked" by ***to***, but there are exceptions, notably...

> 1: Verbs of perception *(**feel, hear, notice, see, watch**)*
>    *"I saw him do it"*
>    2: ***let***
>    *"I let him do it"*
>    3: ***make***
>    *"I made him do it"*

If the primary verb isn't covered above<sup>①</sup> (and isn't an auxiliary/modal such as *can, may, must, shall, will*) the infinitive requires ***to***...

> *"I permit you **to** do it"*
>    *"I ask you **to** do it"*
>    *"I encourage you **to** do it"*
>    etc., etc.

See [here](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/infinitive_without_to.htm) for more information on using the infinitive without ***to***.

---

<sup>①</sup> I just copied a list of verbs from the site I linked to, but it seems incomplete; *"I helped him do it"* is at least "valid", even if some might prefer ***to do***. Plus there's *"I had him do it"* (where no-one would endorse the "marked infinitive" form).

Comment: The last examples you give are not exceptions: they're subordinate clauses with _subjunctives_; not infinitives. You can insert a _that_: “I suggest that he do that”. You can also use the infinitive (though it is rare and, to me at least, quite inelegant), in which case _to_ is necessary: “I recommended him to do it”. (Note the subject in the subordinate clause being nominative, and the infinitive one oblique.)

Comment: @Janus: You're quite right - I just got so carried away fannying about with that **①** symbol I didn't have enough brain power left to think carefully about what I was actually *saying*. If I can't think of any other exceptions apart from auxiliary/modal/let/make (and if you can't help me out with any! :) I think I might have to revert that edit.

Comment: “I had him do it” is the only one I can think of.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, Fumblefingers, Although it could be a subjunctive, it's easily as likely (in British English in any case) to just be a present tense verb ***I suggest he does that on Monday***. Another proper exception, however, is ***help***:  ***I helped her do her homework***

Comment: @Janus: Your *had* and my *help* seem like enough to justify an edit. If that's all we can come up with I think the "There's a general principle, with a few exceptions as noted" approach still holds true.

Comment: @Araucaria: Very true. The fact that the ***do*** can be "tensed" as ***he does*** proves it's not an infinitive.

Comment: +1 Although I don't like the 'marked' shenanigans :) [ - though I appreciate the scare quotes]

Comment: @Araucaria: If you don't like "marked" (terminology which I think is more favoured by linguists), perhaps you'd prefer "bare infinitive" (which seems to be more popular among grammarians).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not really, that was more of a lighthearted joke. It's just that I don't believe that ***to*** is a Verb Phrase marker. I'm a bit of a freak and I tend to side with Geoff Pullum that it's a non-finite auxiliary. Perhaps even a non-finite modal verb... But, I'm in a minority there, so...   :)