# Usage of "to" before verbs after "let me"

Tags: verbs, science

I'm actually writing a scientific article, and my professor is correcting all my (numerous) grammar errors.

One in particular is bugging me. In my article I wrote

> "[object] that lets us introduce [object]"

and was corrected into

> "[object] that lets us  **to** introduce [object]"

My form is totally wrong? Or are they both correct? And why?

---

As ["I let him do it" and "I allow him to do it", why exactly does one require 'to'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177788/i-let-him-do-it-and-i-allow-him-to-do-it-why-exactly-does-one-require-to) shows, the base rule imposes to not use the "to". My question here is a bit more specific.

Is the expression used above indicated/correct for a formal/scientific document?

Comment: *Lets us introduce* is correct. Alternatively, one can write: *Allows/permits us to introduce*. The latter is more formal and probably better suited to a scientific article.

Comment: Your professor's native Romance language or Hebrew, or numerous other languages that use the infinitive there, make his/her ear crave the 'to' that English does use there.

Comment: Specifically: *let* takes an unmarked infinitival complement, *allow* and *permit* take marked infinitival comments. English is so logical!